# UninitializedPropertyAccessException:

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-debug

I'm working on Android development using Kotlin, and encountering an issue with a lateinit var named polyline. The error I'm getting suggests that even though I assigned a value to polyline inside a function called from the onCreate, the app is still crashing with the message that polyline has not been initialized.

Pls how do I go about this?
Is there something I'm missing?

See the code below. I removed all unneccessary codes for this question

```
class CustomerMapActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var polyline: String


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCustomerMapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val pickUpLocation = "Hall 2 Car Park, Benin City, Nigeria"
        val dropOffLocation = "Nadia Bakery, Benin City, Nigeria"
        val apiKey = R.string.google_api_key.toString()

        routesDetails(pickUpLocation, dropOffLocation, apiKey)


    }


    override fun onMapReady(mMap: GoogleMap) {
        
        drawRouteOnMap()

    }


    private fun routesDetails(origin: String, destination: String, apiKey: String){

        val routeService = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RouteService::class.java)

        val requestCall = routeService.getRoutes(origin, destination, apiKey)
        requestCall.enqueue(object: Callback<RoutesResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<RoutesResponse>, response: Response<RoutesResponse>) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    if (routeResponse != null && routeResponse.routes.isNotEmpty()){


                        polyline = response.body()?.routes?.get(0)?.overview_polyline?.points.toString()

                    }else{
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RoutesResponse>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })
    }



    private fun drawRouteOnMap() {
        val decodedPolyline = PolyUtil.decode(polyline)
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide errors from the logcat ? Going to answer asa I see the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Without the stacktrace or additional code, we can only really do guesses as to what the root cause it.

With that said, my guess would be that `drawRouteOnMap()` is being called (via `onMapReady(...)`) before your call to `routeService.getRoutes(origin, destination, apiKey)` completes successfully.

Comment: If your guess is right, how do I solve the issue then?

Comment: Don't draw the route to the map until you've (successfully) received the response? :-)